# Why can't my C# application load my C++ dll?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, file-not-found

I want to use C++ code in a C# application, so I wrote a DLL in C++.
Because it's the first time that I create a C++ DLL, I started by creating a 'test' dll. Here's the code

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void DisplayHelloFromDLL()
    {
        printf("Hello from DLL !\n");
    }
}
```

Than I made a very simple C# application:

```
class DllTest {
    [DllImport("Test.dll")]
    public static extern void DisplayHelloFromDLL();

    public static void UseDll() {
        DisplayHelloFromDLL();
    }
}
```

After, I built both applications and moved the executable and the dll in the same folder. But when I ran the executable, it showed the following message:

> Unhandled exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Test.dll': The specified module could not be found

Answer (score 1):

you need to store the DLL in debug folder.
and try this command to check that method is exported properly

```
dumpbin /exports Test.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check the target platform of both dll and exe.

**Edit:** When Target are different the exception is ***BadImageFormatException***

You will have the ***DllNotFoundException*** when the dll or ***one of its dependencies*** is not found.

For example, when you compile a debug version of the DLL with VisualStudio, it needs the debug runtimes (which are not installed on machine without the IDE).

you can check your dll dependencies using the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

This tools will also helps you to see the targetted system (x86/x64) and the exported functions (use it on the dll, the program will not show you the [DllImport] dependencies)